# Please explain in detail the logic behind the output of x &(~0 << n)

Tags: bit-manipulation

I have doubt in logic behind `x &(~0 <<n)`.
First of all I could not get the meaning of `~0`. When I tried this in Java it showed `-1`. How 
can we represent `-1` in binary and differentiate it from the positive numbers?

Comment: `~0` and `-1` are the same thing: `-x = ~(x - 1)` (two's complement definition of negation), fill in `x = 1`, you get `-1 = ~0`.

Answer (score 2):

The most common way (and the way that Java uses) to represent negative numbers, is called [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). As mentioned in my comment, one way to calculate the negative in this system is `-x = ~(x - 1)`. An other, equivalent way, is `-x = ~x + 1`.

For example, in 8bit,

```
 00000001  // 1
 00000000  // 1 - 1
 11111111  // ~(1 - 1) = ~0 = -1
```

Adding one to `11111111` would wrap to zero - it makes sense to call "the number such that adding one to it result in zero" minus one.

The numbers with the highest bit set are regarded as negative.

The wikipedia article I linked to contains more information.

As for `x & (~0 << n)`, `~0` is just a way to represent "all ones" (which also happens to be -1, which is irrelevant for this use really). For most `n`, "all ones" shifted left by `n` is a bunch of ones followed by `n` zeroes.

In total, that expression clears the lower `n` bits of `x`.
At least, for `0 <= n <= 31`.

`a << n` in Java, where `a` is an `int`, is equivalent to `a << (n & 31)`.

Answer (score 0):

Every bit of the byte 0 is 0, and every bit of -1 is 1, so the bitwise negation of 0 is -1.

Hence ~0 is -1.

As for the rest of the question: what are you actually asking?

Comment: lets say for a binary number: "1" how can I say if it is 1 or -1

Comment: @Akshit What is the width of the variable? What is the endian of the processor? In general for an 8 bit int you'd see 00000001 for 1 and 10000001 for -1 but it depends.

Comment: @asawyer no you wouldn't, two's complement is far more common than sign+magnitude

Comment: @harold For a specific architecture. The question is general to the point of meaningless though.

Comment: @asawyer sure, choose the least common thing.. OP mentioned Java by the way, Java uses two's complement.

Comment: @harold That's a pretty good point. +1 for your answer as well.